# Multithreaded results in slower performance in C

Tags: c, multithreading, performance

I am implementing a realtime signal processing algorithm in C and I am trying to parallelise a section of the code using multithreading.

The code for the single threaded implementation is

```
void calcTheta(float *theta, float **s, float ***q, float ***g,
               int *Ki, int m, int numObv, int numTask) {
    int i, j, k;

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        theta[i] = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < numObv; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < numTask; k++) {
                theta[i] += (Ki[k] * (pow(fabs(q[i][j][k]), 2) / g[i][j][k]) - s[i][k]) /
                             (s[i][k] * (s[i][k] - (pow(fabs(q[i][j][k]), 2) / g[i][j][k])));
            }//k
        }//j
        theta[i] = (numTask * numObv) / theta[i];
    }//i
}
```

The multithreaded implementation uses a thread spooling idea where I create a few threads and keep signalling them to process with specific data arrays. The code is below:

```
#define NUM_THREADS_THETA 2
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#define READY 1
#define DONE 0

struct threadThetaData {
    float *theta;
    float **s;
    float ***q;
    float ***g;
    int *Ki;
    int numObv;
    int numTask;
    int threadId;
};

struct threadThetaData dataArrayTheta[NUM_THREADS_THETA];
int termThread[NUM_THREADS_THETA];
int statusThread[NUM_THREADS_THETA];
int iVal[NUM_THREADS_THETA];
pthread_mutex_t mutexThreadProc[NUM_THREADS_THETA];
pthread_mutex_t mutexMainProc[NUM_THREADS_THETA];
pthread_cond_t condThreadProc[NUM_THREADS_THETA];
pthread_cond_t condMainProc[NUM_THREADS_THETA];

void *doProcTheta(void *threadArg) {
    struct threadThetaData *myData = (struct threadThetaData *)threadArg;

    float *theta = myData->theta;
    float **s = myData->s;
    float ***q = myData->q;
    float ***g = myData->g;
    int *Ki = myData->Ki;
    int numObv = myData->numObv;
    int numTask = myData->numTask;
    int threadId = myData->threadId;

    int j, k;

    while(1) {
        //printf("thread %d waiting for signal from master..\n", threadId);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexThreadProc[threadId]);
        while (statusThread[threadId] != READY)
            pthread_cond_wait(&condThreadProc[threadId], &mutexThreadProc[threadId]);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexThreadProc[threadId]);

        //printf("thread %d got signal from master..\n", threadId);

        if (termThread[threadId] == TRUE)
            pthread_exit(NULL);

        theta[iVal[threadId]] = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < numObv; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < numTask; k++) {
                theta[iVal[threadId]] += (Ki[k]*(pow(fabs(q[iVal[threadId]][j][k]),2)/g[iVal[threadId]][j][k]) - s[iVal[threadId]][k])/(s[iVal[threadId]][k]*(s[iVal[threadId]][k] - (pow(fabs(q[iVal[threadId]][j][k]),2)/g[iVal[threadId]][j][k])));
            }//k
        }//j
        theta[iVal[threadId]] = (numTask*numObv)/theta[iVal[threadId]];

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexMainProc[threadId]);
        statusThread[threadId] = DONE;
        pthread_cond_signal(&condMainProc[threadId]);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexMainProc[threadId]);

        //printf("thread %d signaled to master..\n", threadId);
    }
}

void calcTheta(float *theta,float **s,float ***q,float ***g,int *Ki,int m, int numObv, int numTask)
{
    int i,j;

    pthread_t thetaThreads[NUM_THREADS_THETA];
    int numThreadBlks = m/NUM_THREADS_THETA;
    int numThreadRem = m%NUM_THREADS_THETA;
    int mCount = 0;

    for(i=0;i<NUM_THREADS_THETA;i++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_init(&mutexThreadProc[i], NULL);
        pthread_mutex_init(&mutexMainProc[i], NULL);
        pthread_cond_init (&condThreadProc[i], NULL);
        pthread_cond_init (&condMainProc[i], NULL);
        dataArrayTheta[i].theta = theta;
        dataArrayTheta[i].s = s;
        dataArrayTheta[i].q = q;
        dataArrayTheta[i].g = g;
        dataArrayTheta[i].Ki = Ki;
        dataArrayTheta[i].numObv = numObv;
        dataArrayTheta[i].numTask = numTask;
        dataArrayTheta[i].threadId = i;
        termThread[i] = FALSE;
        statusThread[i] = DONE;
        pthread_create(&thetaThreads[i],NULL,doProcTheta,(void *)&dataArrayTheta[i]);

    }

    for(i=0;i<numThreadBlks;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<NUM_THREADS_THETA;j++)
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexThreadProc[j]);
            statusThread[j] = READY;
            iVal[j] = mCount;
            mCount++;
            pthread_cond_signal(&condThreadProc[j]);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexThreadProc[j]);
            //printf("Signaled thread %d from master ... Waiting  on signal ..\n",j);
        }

        for(j=0;j<NUM_THREADS_THETA;j++)
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexMainProc[j]);
            while (statusThread[j] != DONE)
                pthread_cond_wait(&condMainProc[j], &mutexMainProc[j]);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexMainProc[j]);
            //printf("Got signal from thread %d to  master \n",j);
        }

    }

    for(j=0;j<numThreadRem;j++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexThreadProc[j]);
        statusThread[j] = READY;
        iVal[j] = mCount;
        mCount++;
        pthread_cond_signal(&condThreadProc[j]);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexThreadProc[j]);
    }

    for(j=0;j<numThreadRem;j++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexMainProc[j]);
        while (statusThread[j] != DONE)
            pthread_cond_wait(&condMainProc[j], &mutexMainProc[j]);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexMainProc[j]);
    }

    for(j=0;j<NUM_THREADS_THETA;j++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexThreadProc[j]);
        statusThread[j] = READY;
        termThread[j] = TRUE;
        pthread_cond_signal(&condThreadProc[j]);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexThreadProc[j]);

        pthread_join(thetaThreads[j],NULL);

        pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutexThreadProc[j]);
        pthread_cond_destroy(&condThreadProc[j]);
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutexMainProc[j]);
        pthread_cond_destroy(&condMainProc[j]);
    }

}
```

Array dimensions :

```
float theta[m];
float s[m][numTask];
float q[m][numObv][numTask];
float g[m][numObv][numTask];
int Ki[numTask];
```

For a specific dataset where

```
m=661
numObv=96
numTask=1024
```

the runtimes are :

```
Single threaded : 4.5 seconds
Multithreaded with 2 threads : 6.9 seconds
```

I expected the runtimes for the multithreaded code to give me some performance improvement over the single threaded code when its the other way around . Any pointers to what I am missing here would be much appreciated.

Comment: not enough work between locks results in more time spent dealing with locks than time saved working in parallel.

Comment: I can move the calculation of theta in the doProcTheta function to inside the lock, would that help ??

Comment: Only loosely related to your question: If you don't know it yet, have a look at OpenMP.

Comment: @anshu: it might, it might not... Only benchmarking will tell you.  Note however that the more you do inside the locks, the less chances you give for parallelism.

Comment: I have had openMP in mind but I wanted to avoid using external libraries and use the in-built linux libraries as much as possible, but I will try to give openMP a shot as well ..

Comment: You are assigning specific jobs to specific threads. That's not smart. You want whichever thread happens to run to do whatever work happens to need to be done. Use a queue of work.

Comment: From a quick look at the sequential code, since you are summing up in theta[i], you do not seem to need any lock. Just fire up as many threads as you have cores to process each theta[i]. When m is reached, the threads exit.

Comment: @Tarik : I tried to avoid spawning a lot of threads to keep the overhead minimum, the locks are used to synchronise the child threads with the main thread

Comment: this has absolutely nothing to do with *"realtime"*. Please dont just use random words because they may *"look cool"*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your multi threaded implementation seems way to complex for the problem at hand. The single threaded code shows that each `theta` element is calculated independently from all other `theta` elements.

So you don't need the mutexes and conditionals as there are no need for data exchange/synchronization between the threads. Just let the threads deal with different ranges of the `theta` calculation.

With `m=661` and 2 threads, then the first thread should calculate `theta` in range 0..330 and the second thread should calculate `theta` in range 331..660. Launch the two threads and wait for them to finish (aka join).

You can nearly use the single threaded code for a multi threaded implementation. All you need is to add a start-index to the function.

Comment: +1 Apart from what you wrote, I also don't understand the need for `while (1)` inside the processing function. And the usage of mutexes is completely unnecessary.